# System.InvalidOperationException: Specific element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect is first

Tags: c#, wpf, process, writablebitmap

I am trying to print some paragraphs and image using Flow Document As shown in Code below

```
Paragraph invoiceID = new Paragraph(new Run("Invoice No : "+ txtInvoiceID.Text));
Paragraph qty001 = new Paragraph(new Run("Quantity : " + qtyText.Text));
Paragraph date001 = new Paragraph(new Run("Date : " +txtInvoiceDate.Text));

Section sec = new Section();
sec.Blocks.Add(invoiceID);
sec.Blocks.Add(qty001);
sec.Blocks.Add(date001);

FlowDocument fd = new FlowDocument();
PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();

fd.PageHeight = pd.PrintableAreaHeight;
fd.PageWidth = pd.PrintableAreaWidth;
fd.PagePadding = new Thickness(50);
fd.ColumnWidth = pd.PrintableAreaWidth;
fd.Blocks.Add(sec);
fd.Blocks.Add(new BlockUIContainer(barCodeImage));

IDocumentPaginatorSource dps = fd;
pd.PrintDocument(dps.DocumentPaginator,"Desciption");
```

I know image is locked by the process but how i can unlock this image ??

Any help please

Thanks

Jazaib

Comment: Image locking has nothing to do with the question posed in your title.

Answer (score -1):

In WPF every control can have one parent only, since you already defined barCodeImage in xaml, it is child of some container.
so you can either remove it from the container or clone the image